# Is there a difference between the way Dagger2 treats @Singleton and custom sopes?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger-2

The question is in the subject, yet I'll repeat it again:

Is there a difference between the way Dagger2 treats @Singleton and custom sopes?

Also, if a class is annotated with some scope, is there a convenient way to expose it as a different scope (or unscoped), or do I need to write a provider method?

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between the way Dagger2 treats @Singleton and custom sopes.

Lets say we are using @User

```
@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface User {
}


@Module
public class TwitterModule {
    private final String user;

    public TwitterModule(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Provides
    @User
    Tweeter provideTweeter(TwitterApi twitterApi) {
        return new Tweeter(twitterApi, user);
    }

    @Provides
    @User
    Timeline provideTimeline(TwitterApi twitterApi) {
        return new Timeline(twitterApi, user);
    }

}


@Module
public class NetworkModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient() {
        return new OkHttpClient();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    TwitterApi provideTwitterApi(OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
        return new TwitterApi(okHttpClient);
    }

}


@Singleton
@Component(modules = {NetworkModule.class})
public interface ApiComponent {

    TwitterApi api();

    TwitterComponent twitterComponent(TwitterModule twitterModule);
}

@User
@Subcomponent(modules = {TwitterModule.class})
public interface TwitterComponent {

    TwitterApplication app();
}


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    TwitterComponent twitterComponentForUserOne,twitterComponentForUserTwo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ApiComponent apiComponent = DaggerApiComponent.create();

        twitterComponentForUserOne = apiComponent.twitterComponent(new TwitterModule("Amit Shekhar"));

        twitterComponentForUserTwo = apiComponent.twitterComponent(new TwitterModule("Sumit Shekhar"));

        // use twitterComponentOne and twitterComponentTwo for two users independently 

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        twitterComponentForUserOne = null;
        twitterComponentForUserTwo = null;
    }
}
```

Here just we have to make sure that when we do not need the twitterComponent for that user. We have to assign null so that it gets garbage collected as I am doing here in onDestroy();

Finally, everything depends on component,if you have an instance of component in Application class it is not going to be garbage collected for whole application life-cycle.